# python: how to convert "x days ago" or "x month ago" to date?

Tags: python, date

How to convert the following statements to dates (no time need) in python?

```
10 days ago
about 2 months ago
```

Here are the code I made so far:

```
import re
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def string_to_delta(s):
    value = int(re.search(r'\d+', s).group())
    if "day" in s:
        value = value*1
    elif "month" in s:
        value = value *30   
    date_ago = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=value)).date() 
    str_date= date_ago.strftime("%d %B %Y")
    return str_date
```

It worked, but I feel awkward.

Comment: I would get the current date using `datetime` package then put an algorithm, where if in weeks multiple it by 4 because 4 weeks in a month. Read the docs i believe there is a offset method

Comment: also you cant just ask for an answer without trying something

Comment: @Smashed, sure.  I have tried and made something (see update above), but it is kind of convoluted solution

Comment: Hey If it works it works. Here people will downvote if you just simply ask questions.

Comment: Learned my lesson!  :)  Thanks buddy

Comment: If your code works then you could submit it to codereview.SE If the formats may wary you could `pip install parsedatetime` and use `parsedatetime.Calendar().parseDT("about 2 months ago", date.today())`

Answer (score 5):

- Use a regex to get the relevant part:

  ```
  value, unit = re.search(r'(\d+) (\w+) ago', 'about 2 months ago').groups()
  ```
- Create the `dateutil.relativedelta`:

  ```
  from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
  if not unit.endswith('s'): unit += 's'
  delta = relativedelta(**{unit: int(value)})
  ```
- Subtract it from the current date:

  ```
  from datetime import datetime
  print datetime.now() - delta
  ```

So a whole function would be:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from datetime import datetime

def ago_do_date(ago):
    value, unit = re.search(r'(\d+) (\w+) ago', ago).groups()
    if not unit.endswith('s'):
        unit += 's'
    delta = relativedelta(**{unit: int(value)})
    print datetime.now() - delta
```

Comment: Regarding dateutil, it seems a great tool.  However, I have trouble install it.  Got the following error message:  "  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement dateutil (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for dateutil"